# Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, neo4j

I use neo4j 2.2.4

I try this program ,and this is my test code

```
package neo4j.rest.client;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
public class MyRestClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyRestClient jersey = new MyRestClient();
    jersey.createNode();
    jersey.sendCypher();        
}
public void createNode(){   
    //Create a REST Client
    Client client = Client.create();
    //Define a resource (REST Endpoint) which needs to be Invoked 
    //for creating a Node
    WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:7474").path("/db/data/node");
    //Define properties for the node.
    JSONObject node = new JSONObject();
    node.append("Name", "John");        
    System.out.println(node.toString());        
    //Invoke the rest endpoint as JSON request
    ClientResponse res = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .entity(node.toString())
    .post(ClientResponse.class);
    //Print the URI of the new Node
    System.out.println("URI of New Node = " + res.getLocation());       
}
public void sendCypher() {
    //Create a REST Client
    Client client = Client.create();
    //Define a resource (REST Endpoint) which needs to be Invoked 
    //for executing Cypher Query
    WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:7474").path("/db/data/cypher");
    //Define JSON Object and Cypher Query
    JSONObject cypher = new JSONObject();
    cypher.accumulate("query", "match n return n limit 10");
    //Invoke the rest endpoint as JSON request
    ClientResponse res = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(cypher.toString())
    .post(ClientResponse.class);
    //Print the response received from the Server
    System.out.println(res.getEntity(String.class));
}
}
```

And this is my error information,

> {"Name":["John"]}
>   Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:553)
>       at neo4j.rest.client.MyRestClient.createNode(MyRestClient.java:30)
>       at neo4j.rest.client.MyRestClient.main(MyRestClient.java:14)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
>       at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:483)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:213)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:300)
>       at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:316)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:992)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:928)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:846)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1087)
>       at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$1$1.getOutputStream(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:225)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.commitWrite(CommittingOutputStream.java:117)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.CommittingOutputStream.write(CommittingOutputStream.java:89)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
>       at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
>       at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
>       at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.util.ReaderWriter.writeToAsString(ReaderWriter.java:191)
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.writeToAsString(AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider.java:128)
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:88)
>       at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider.writeTo(StringProvider.java:58)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:300)
>       at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:204)
>       at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:147)
>       ... 6 more

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your server is running and accessible at http://localhost:7474?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check if your Neo4j server is up and running. Just open http://localhost:7474 in your browser.
- Your code would work if you use default settings of Neo4j. Because authorization is enabled by default. You have two options:

  1. Add authorization headers into your request

     client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("neo4j","your_password"));

     - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html
  2. Disable authorization

**neo4j-server.properties**

```
# Disable authorization
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```